# Jquery (window.open) doesn't work in safari

Tags: jquery

the code works fine in desktop browsers, but when i trying to access from iphone, ipad the click doesn't work maybe it due to pop block or anything. i tried many ways but no luck.

here is my code

```
var myWindow = window.open("stackoverflow.com"+$("#ord_box_cur_id").val(),"Print","width=400");
```

i have tried removing with, same result. :(

```
var myWindow = window.open("stackoverflow.com"+$("#ord_box_cur_id").val(),"Print");
```

i tried with opening with new window but still same result, click doesn't give any response.

thanks for looking and for your help

here is full function

```
    $("#button_accept").click(function(){           
        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'ajax/accept.php',
              dataType: 'html',
              cache: false,
              data:  { order_id: $("#ord_box_cur_id").val(), admin_comment: $("#ord_admin_comment").val()} ,
              beforeSend:function(){

              },
              success:function(data){
                if(parseInt(data)==1){



                    var myWindow = window.open('zhttp://www.google.com', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');



                    //myWindow.print();

                    $(".popupcontainer").hide();



                    $(".order_tr_"+$("#ord_box_cur_id").val()).removeClass("new cancelled");
                    $(".order_tr_"+$("#ord_box_cur_id").val()).children(".tr_pstat").html("Processed");

                }
                else
                    alert("Network error, please retry!");
              },
              error:function(){
                alert("Error");
              }
        });
});
```

Comment: Touch devices don't have a 'click' event. You need to bind to the touch events.

Comment: @TiesonT. i posted my full function code

Comment: @TiesonT. All touch browser that I've ever encountered will fire a click event after the touch events. Otherwise there would be massive compatibility issues.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I believe that is a simulated click event, and I know I have had issues in the past with getting click events to work properly on mobile devices. Granted, that was a few years ago, so perhaps jQuery handles those events better now. It may depend on whether the targeted element is well-formed or not.

Comment: @TiesonT. Simulated in the sense that it wasn't an actual click that fired it, otherwise it's real. It (along with `mousedown` and `mouseup`) will only fire if `touchstart` and `touchend` complete without a `touchmove` event, possibly after a short delay to check for double-tap. Anyhow, @FAAD your code has `zhttp://` for a URL protocol. Is that possibly your problem?

Comment: no z before http is for printing on wireless devices...